# Get-ADUser - searching for expired account. Using variables in command

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, powershell-5.0

I am currently working on a Powershell GUI script to help my team easier find accounts with expired passwords, disabled accounts etc and to output these to a CSV. It revolves almost entirely around the "**Get-ADUser**" command. So far almost everything has worked, bar finding accounts with expired passwords.

I've researched this a lot already but there seems to be no *easy* way of finding expired accounts using Get-ADUser. I know I can use **Search-ADAccount** instead but it would be very awkward to do so (as I would need to re-write a lot of code).

`Get-Aduser -Properties * -Filter {PasswordExpired -eq $true}` just draws a blank.

I've found a partial solution over at https://serverfault.com/questions/805526/get-aduser-password-expired-filter-not-working-correctly/805611

For example,

`Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter * | ? {$_.PasswordExpired -eq $True -and $_.Enabled -eq $true} | Select-Object name, enabled | Export-Csv "C:\report.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

works just fine but if I try to assign the 'middle' of the command i.e

`{$_.PasswordExpired -eq $True -and $_.Enabled -eq $true}`

to a variable and then substitute it into the command I either get an error, a list of all those in my AD or nobody at all. The rational for substituting in a variable is to allow for the possible account statuses (that the user can choose from by selecting a radio button).

I've tried the various permutations of double and single quotes, including and not including curly brackets etc but Powershell will not give me a break!

Thanks!

Comment: Your filter should not be a scriptblock; try `Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter 'PasswordExpired -eq "TRUE" -and Enabled -eq "TRUE"'`. I won't swear to it (not on an AD system now to test), but I _think_ you may be able to omit both instances of `-eq "TRUE"`.

Comment: Hi Jeff. I've given that a try. 'PasswordExpired' is apparently a method (or calculated value) and therefore works differently from filtered properties (for Get-ADUser such as 'Enabled'.

Answer (score 2):

The `Get-ADUser` cmdlet exposes the `PasswordExpired` extended property, which is a boolean indicating if the password is expired. It is based on the `msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed` attribute. However, you cannot filter with this property.

This would mean you can check the UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED bit on that property:

```powershell
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Properties 'msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed' | 
    Where-Object {($_.'msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed' -band  0x800000) -eq 0x800000} |    # UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED --> 0x800000 = 8388608
    Select-Object Name, Enabled | Export-Csv "C:\report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

You can speed up the above by extending the filter to rule out users with `PasswordNeverExpires` and `PasswordNotRequired` both $false:

```powershell
$filter = "Enabled -eq 'True' -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq 'False' -and PasswordNotRequired -eq 'False'"
Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordNotRequired, 'msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed' | 
    Where-Object {($_.'msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed' -band 0x800000) -eq 0x800000} |    # UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED --> 0x800000 = 8388608
    Select-Object Name, Enabled | Export-Csv "C:\report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon I've found a solution over on Stack Exchange.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/723217/find-out-if-password-expired-or-when-it-expires-for-user-in-a-specific-ou

Early tests suggest it works.